# How to display first two occurence of Table Data | Oracle |

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Scenario where my table contains dummy data

The particular data is repeated multiple time from that only first two occurrence need to be fetched

DATA in the table is in below format

```
TAB_A | TAB_B
AB    | 12
AB    | 12
AB    | 2131
CF    | 12313
CF    | 13
CF    | 45
MG    | 424
MG    | 242
MG    | 546
VR    | 868
VR    | 312
VR    | 35
VR    | 68
```

I need output in this format below only first two occurrence of **TAB_A column**

```
TAB_A |TAB_B
AB    |12
AB    |12
CF    |12313
CF    |13
MG    |424
MG    |242
VR    |868
VR    |312
```

I tried partition method not able to implement logic and even tried rownum order by

Comment: please dont put the image..instead of that put the content of table data

Comment: @Andrew pls this time consider image next time I will post table content

Comment: I think you actually mean "table", not "database" and giving a _column_ the prefix "TAB" is one strange naming convention.

Comment: I don't know about Andrew, but I can't access images when I'm in current network so ... good luck till next time. Hopefully, someone who sees those images will assist.

Comment: Expected output is not clear. Can you please share the logic behind fetching the output? Which two records do you want? Is there any column like date or id based on which we can do ordering to find the furst two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() as below :

```
SELECT tab_a, tab_b 
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tab_a ORDER BY tab_b) AS row_number 
  FROM test t) T
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eeaee/10)

Comment: Hm, this does return two of each but does it return first two of each ?

Comment: It does return first two of each order by tab_b value. If you want "first two" you need an order by something, that's mandatory. Data inside table are not sorted so you need to apply the sort you wish. So that why I suggested a sort by tab_b value which seemed the most logical.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
    select *
from (select TAB_A,TAB_B,
      rank() over (partition by TAB_A order by TAB_B) rank
      from test)
      test
where rank <= 2
```

Check fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eeaee/19

Comment: This first sql will only return LM from the example data because `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2`

Comment: I think that row_number would be better in this case if there are 3 identicals values of tab_b for the same tab_a

Comment: yes i have edited my answer and tested and its working

Comment: Really guy ? build your own test no ? Look at this example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/481fc/1  this is not working

Comment: really strange try with the schema i build and example ..you can also verify the answer..see the link

Comment: This is not strange at all, this is because you use rank which will give the same rank value for all identical tab_b value. That's why if you have 3 identicals value of tab_b for the same tab_a, like in my example, it will give the same rank (i.e. rank 1) and it will be selected because rank 1 is <= 2. FInally you have first 3 rows selected instead of 2 in this particular case. That's why I said row_number should be better than rank !